# Get all member of groups contained by OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get all users, which are part of a group.
With a single group it is no problem for me:

```
(&
    (objectCategory=Person)
    (sAMAccountName=*)
    (memberOf=CN=...,OU=...,DC=..)
)
```

But I need now to get all members of groups which are part by an OU.
My idea was to use following:

```
(&
    (objectCategory=Person)
    (sAMAccountName=*)
    (memberOf=CN=*,OU=...,DC=..)
)
```

But it seems not to work (the result is empty). I am using Apache LDAP Studio for testing.
Is there any possibility to filter the users like this?

Comment: Define 'seems not to work'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I don't think that you can use wildcard caracters in DN comparaison in Active-Directory.

ExtensibleMatch explained [here](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) may perhaps allow you to build filters on the DN path, but it's not supported in Active Directory. As far as I know you've got the following solution to do what you want:

- First look for all groups in the OU, then for each group get all members.